# complex inner join sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

You are my last hope. I've spend all day but I haven't decided how to create this query.

This is my current database diagram

[image]

Every storage have 1 roster

Every roster consist from chief and worker. Information about them is on stuff table .

What I try to do? Get all storage(square adress), worker_name, worker_surname, chief_name, chief_surname.

What I have so far

```
select storage_address,
storage_square,
 stuffs.stuff_name as chiefSurname, 
stuffs.stuff_surname as chiefName from storages 
inner join storageRoster on storageRoster.storageRoster_id=storages.storage_roster_id 
inner join Chiefs on storageRoster.chief_id = Chiefs.chief_id 
inner join stuffs on Chiefs.chief_stuff_id = stuffs.stuff_id
```

But in this query I can only get chiefs on every storage. Help please. I am desperate.

Comment: inner join will return only matches,with out data ,its hard t help,you can try debugging by keeping one join at a time

Comment: You have to join Workers and another Stuffs (for obtaining Workers data) to your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the stuff table twice, once for worker and once for chief:

```
select storage_address,
storage_square,
cs.stuff_name as chiefSurname, 
cs.stuff_surname as chiefName,
ws.stuff_name as workerSurname, 
ws.stuff_surname as workerName 
from storages 
inner join storageRoster on storageRoster.storageRoster_id=storages.storage_roster_id 
inner join Chiefs on storageRoster.chief_id = Chiefs.chief_id 
inner join stuffs cs on Chiefs.chief_stuff_id = cs.stuff_id
inner join Workers on storageRoster.worker_id = Workers.chief_id 
inner join ws cs on Workers.worker_stuff_id = ws.stuff_id
```